# Pyramid: sending miscellaneous config to the application factory

Tags: python, configuration-files, pyramid

I have setup the Pyramid configuration file like this:

```
[app:main]
...

[server:main]
...


[memcache]
# memcache config

[zeromq]
# zeromq xonfig
```

Now inside my `app_factory`, I want to get all the config -- not just the `app:main` section but also the `memcache`, `zeromq` and other possible sections.

How should I do this.

The reason I am separating the config into different sections is because my app uses lots of disparate services and I don't want to cobble all the config together into the `app:main` section.

One way to do this is to manually pull the config into the application by reading the config file. Then you have to somehow know what mode (development or production) the app is running. Also, there's the overhead of parsing the config multiple times (because the paste-deploy will do it first).

Is there a better and more elegant solution to this?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but what I usually do is I put all in `[app:main]`, but I namespace with dots. Like `service1.url`, `service2.url`.

Comment: I do the same. For example: google.analytics.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass application specific config into the ini files:

```
[app:xyz]
    something = True
```

Then in your `main` function (application factory), you can access it as

```
settings['something']
```

More info:

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/environment.html#adding-a-custom-setting

Comment: Didn't your question specifically say you **didn't** want to "cobble" together all the settings into the `[app:main]` section? Oh well.

Comment: @MichaelMerickel But this is not `[app:main]` section. It's the `[app:xyz]` section that I am putting the config under

Comment: What am I missing here in your working solution? Your `main()` will only have available to it settings that are within the `[app:...]` section for which the `main()` is invoked. It cannot see other `[app:...]` sections. The section that is loaded is dependent on the options to `pserve` (which defaults to main, but can be overridden on the CLI).

Comment: @MichaelMerickel Are you saying that `main()` will not be able to access the config under `[app:xyz]` section?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you'll have to parse the config file again if you want to take this approach. You can grab the file via `config_file = global_config['__file__']` in your `main` and parse it yourself using the stdlib `ConfigParser`.

If you like this INI format with separate sections, the Mozilla Services has a nice little module you can use to handle all of this for you. It does value conversion (attempts to cast values to integers or booleans). It supports extending your config with other sections, such as `[foo:bar] key = value`, which when parsed will return you a simple dictionary containing `settings['foo.bar.key'] == value`. It will also conveniently parse the thing for you so your main can just look like:

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
    config = get_configurator(global_config, **settings)
    settings = config.registry.settings
    # ... do your app configuration
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

https://wiki.mozilla.org/index.php?title=Services/Sync/Server/GlobalConfFile
https://github.com/mozilla-services/mozservices/blob/master/mozsvc/config.py

Comment: There is a python ConfigParser in the stdlib, no need of mozilla

Comment: Of course, but you're missing the point of what their parser does (which uses the ConfigParser). I will update my answer to explain.